# conda-build does not fill git environment variables if CONDA_BLD_PATH is changed

Tags: python, git, jenkins, conda

I want to use GIT_DESCRIBE_TAG and GIT_DESCRIBE_HASH to name our conda packages. So Our meta.yaml basically looks like this:

```
package:
  name: package_name
  version: {{ environ.get('GIT_DESCRIBE_TAG') }}

source:
  git_url: http://bugtracker.company/diffusion/PACKAGE/PACKAGE.git

requirements:

  run:
    - some_package_1 # [win]
    - some_package_2
    - some_package_3 # [win]
    - some_package_4    

build:
  string: {{ environ.get('GIT_DESCRIBE_HASH') }}
```

We use jenkins to set up builds and ages ago jenkins was set up to do:

```
set CONDA_BLD_PATH=%CD%/build
conda build src
```

Since updating conda-build from 2.1.9 to 3.0.15, for some reason all the git environment variables aren't filled anymore. I tried locally on the buildserver with leaving the conda_bld_path to it's standard value and there it works.

Out of curiousity I checked /build/git_cache/bugtracker.company/diffusion/PACKAGE/package.git and found the tags in there (renamed to .git and checked with "git tag"). So the tags should be in the cache that gets downloaded to /build. But the environment variables still aren't filled.

Any guess on what might be going wrong?